# AWStats stuck, but no output on strace: How to debug?

Tags: perl, debugging

A Perl script is stuck,

```
root     1317478 99.8  0.0 264072 22516 ?        R    04:57 478:37 /usr/bin/perl /usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=domain.tld-http -staticlinks -configdir=/usr/local/psa/etc/awstats -output=keywords
```

but when I `strace -f -p`, I only get the output

```
strace: Process 1317478 attached [ Process PID=1317478 runs in x32 mode. ]
```

What's the next step to find out what is going on?

Comment: Likely stuck in a busy loop like in `perl -e 'while(1){}'`. See also [How can I attach a debugger to a running Perl process?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8836711)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the script was waiting on a DNS response that it never received.